# Finding the height of a multiway tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, multiway-tree

How do you find the height of a multi-way tree? If I wanted to find the height of a binary tree, I could do something like this:

```
int height(node *root) {
  if (root == NULL)
    return 0;
  else
    return max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
}
```

But I am not sure if I can apply a similar recursive method to a multiway tree.

Answer (score 4):

The general case would be:

```
int height(node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;
    else {
        // pseudo code
        int max = 0;
        for each child {
            int height = height(child);
            if (height > max) max = height;
        }
        return max + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  In the case of 0 children, you will return a negative height.

Comment: You also walk the tree many times because of the multiple calls to height.  This is very inefficient.

Comment: @jjnguy, no worries.  Just wanted the OP to get the right behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the child nodes are stored.  Lets assume for a second that they are stored in a vector.  You could then use the following to calculate their height.

```
int height(node* root ) {
  if ( !root ) {
    return 0;
  }
  int max = 0;
  for ( vector<node*>::const_iterator it = root->children.begin();
        it != root->children.end();
        it++ ) {
    int cur = height(*it);
    if ( cur > max ) {  
      max = cur;
    }
  }
  return max+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth (almost nothing), this problem renders beautifully in pure-functional languages like SML:

```
fun height Node(children) = (foldl max -1 (map height children)) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it '1 + maximum height of sub-tree starting from any of the child nodes of the (current) root node'?

Note that the binary tree is just a special case of the multi-way tree where the child nodes are known to be the left child and the right child.  The result is zero if the root node pointer is null.

Answer (score 0):

if non-null:

- find the height of each of the children
- take the maximum
- add 1